# Active class add on sidebar of woocommerce product page?

Tags: wordpress

I have use woocommerce plugin. My product page right side list to sub category but in these not display which sub category page active. so if you possible to add active custom add on woocommerce product page.

Answer (score 0):

The current category will have the class `current-cat` assigned to it so you can use some CSS to highlight the link.  The example below changes the link to a red color.  Add it to your style.css file or custom CSS options in your theme.

```
ul.product-categories .current-cat a {
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: But My problem is how to add current-cat to sidebar. Shortcode through category list so how can know which category page open?

Comment: It's already added for you by the shortcode by default.  Copy and paste my CSS and you will see the current category highlighted in red :)

Comment: I already added css for active category because sidebar display both page subcategory and product page also but active class display only subcategory page not product page.